# tableViewSelectionDidChange with addSubview and removeFromSuperview in table row

Tags: swift, nstableview, addsubview

I looked for posts for issues with all 3 functions listed in the title, but my problem is not discussed anywhere. Frankly, my problem is such that it defies logic IMHO.

On selection of a row in my view-based `NSTableView`, I want to show a "Save" button in my last (aka "Action") column. So on `viewDidLoad()` I created my orphan button. Then on `tableViewSelectionDidChange()` I remove it from the superview and add it to my column's `NSTableCellView`. When there's no row selected, there is no button to show. Simple. Below code works perfectly.

```
func tableViewSelectionDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
    let selectedRow = tableView.selectedRow
    btnSave!.removeFromSuperview()
    if selectedRow > -1,
        let rowView = rowView(selectedRow),
        let actionView = rowView.view(atColumn: Column.action.hashValue) as? NSTableCellView {
        actionView.addSubview(btnSave!)
    }
}
```

Wait. Did I say Perfect? It works as long as I use mouse to change the selected row, including selecting below the last row in table which removes selection and any button in previous selected row. However, when I use the keyboard Up/Down keys to change the selection, it does not work.

First I thought the function will get called only if I use mouse to change row selection. However, that's not true. That's true for `tableViewSelectionIsChanging` as per docs and as per facts. But for `tableViewSelectionDidChange` docs don't say it will only work when mouse is used and the facts bear that out. I put print statements and function does get called. I stepped through debugger as well. The mind boggling part is - the method to remove button from superview works, but the one to add button as subview does not work - and only if I use keyboard. How is it possible that the same exact code executes but I get two different outcomes?

Adding remaining functions

I use this to get selected row

```
private func rowView(_ rowIndex: Int, _ make: Bool = false) -> NSTableRowView? {
        return tableView.rowView(atRow: rowIndex, makeIfNecessary: make)
    }
```

I call this in viewDidLoad to create my orphan button

```
private func createButton() {
    btnSave = NSButton(frame: NSRect(x: 10, y: 0, width: 22, height: 16))
    btnSave?.title = "S"
    btnSave?.setButtonType(.momentaryPushIn)
    btnSave?.bezelStyle = .roundRect
}
```

Comment: What is `selectedRow` when you use the keyboard?

Comment: @Willeke If you are asking what is the value? It is either table row index or -1. To be clear, the same lines of codes execute whether I use mouse or keyboard and how I change selection should really be irrelevant. Unfortunately something behind the scenes is producing different outcome. Using latest Xcode on 10.13.3. You can easily reproduce this. Just slam a tableview with one column in a viewcontroller and try what I'm doing.

Comment: How are `btnSave`, `rowView()` and `Column.action.hashValue` declared? Is `addSubview()` always excuted?

Comment: btnSave is just an NSButton with Title,roundrect and momentarypushin. I use btnSave! because it's declaread as NSButton? as a property of ViewController. Column is an enum for my columns beginning at index 0 for hashvalue - convenient, eh? And yes addSubview() always executed. Like I said every line that should execute DOES execute. For the life of me I can't figure out why it does not work when I change selection using keyboard. It should make no difference how I changed the selection given the function is call "after selection did change". Mind boggling. Like I said you can easily reproduce.

Comment: I tried to reproduce but I can't. What does `rowView()` do? Is the button added but not visible?

Comment: @Willeke3 - Sorry. I actually refactored my code because I thought I was making it easier to read. Just a helper function and literally has the following code in it...return tableView.rowView(atRow: rowIndex, makeIfNecessary: make). The function takes a default value of "false", i.e. don't create new row.

Comment: I tried something similar and the row view isn't always created. When I do `tableView.view(atColumn: 1, row: selectedRow, makeIfNecessary: true)`, the button is always added and visible.

Comment: All the rows in my table are visible. So the rowview has to have been created right? Only rows that are "off screen" or below the last row visible because my window size is small may not be created. Also, again it works as long as I use mouse to change the selected row. Sorry, but I'm not getting why row wouldn't be created. Fact of the matter is it is being created and all lines of code execute whether I used mouse or keyboard. For some godforsaken reason I don't see button appear in the row I selected. As soon as I launch app, last row is selected and button is visible. After i change, not

Comment: @Willeke - I owe you an apology. YOU ARE RIGHT. I passed "true" by default and now it !@#$%& works !!! BUT you have to explain to me how?!?!?! Why does rowView available when I use mouse to change the selection, but not when I use keyboard to change the selection. Bug in Apple Code?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe because `mouseDown` uses views to find the new first responder.

Comment: I bow to thee. Thank you!